# Access Postgres on Mac from Windows 10 on VMWare

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, vmware-fusion

I have postgres running on my Mac (OSX 10.13.1). Running Windows 10 in a virtual machine on VMWare Fusion (8.5.8). Requirement is to access a postgres database from an app running on the Windows VM, but I'm having trouble finding documentation and specific instructions about how to configure Postgres appropriately--appreciate any help.

The connection should be secure, and limited to local if possible--really don't want to expose a connection to the external internet.

I gather that there are some configuration settings that need to be made in `postgresql.conf` as well as in `pg_hba.conf`.

Tried adding `listen_address = '*'` to the `postgresql.conf` file, and added `host    all    all    xxx.xx.xxx.x/24    md5` (where x's indicate the IP address for the virtual machine) in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

On the setup screen for the postgres driver on Windows, I'm not sure how to set the driver up to find the database.

[image]

Also:  I found an IP address for the VM on the Mac terminal, but does that change every time the machine restarts, or can it be set to a constant value? I.e. I don't want to have to reset the configuration every time the machine restarts.

Thanks in advance.